# TypeScript: Returned type when accessing undefined key on object is wrong?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I noticed unexpected types when using objects with variable keys in TypeScript.

Given the following code

```js
type MyType = {
  [x: number] : number
}

const o : MyType = {
  0: 1,
}

const a = o[0]; // Return type correctly identified as number
const b = o[1]; // Return type should be undefined and compiler should not allow this
```

I noticed that the type of an object access using `[...]` is not correctly detected when the object type is defined using the `[x: number]` syntax for variable keys.

VSCode shows me that both `a`  and `b` have type `number`. Shouldn't the type be `number | undefined` instead because it can happen that a key is undefined? When logging `a` and `b` to the console, `a` is a `number` while `b` is `undefined`.

The problem becomes more serious when an object of type `MyType` is passed to a function and this function accesses a key in this object and then does something like this:

```js
function fun(o: MyType) : number {
   return o[10000] ?? null  // can be number or null at runtime
}
```

No error is shown. But when the code is run, `o[10000]` is undefined and therefore the return value is `null` which is not a valid number. Imagine using this return value to perform further computations that are all based on the assumption that is is a valid number. This would lead to runtime errors that should have been detected by the compiler (if I don't understand something completely wrong, I am new to TS)

(TypeScript used in these examples is configured by create-react-app, I did not change any settings)

Answer (score 7):

Add `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true` to your tsconfig.json complierOptions object

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the type be number | undefined instead because it can happen that a key is undefined?

You have that option if you want; just define it as:

```
type MyType = {
  [x: number] : number | undefined
}
```

This can be useful if you expect to be accessing random properties that might not exist.

On the other hand though, it's fairly common to use objects in a more disciplined manner that avoids the possibility of accessing nonexistent properties. For example, if you're commonly writing code that uses `Object.keys(o)` or `for ... in` to decide what properties to access, then you're already doing the work to make sure it exists, and it may get frustrating to have typescript always tell you it might be undefined.

Comment: In case anyone wants an "official" answer to this, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778), a request to automatically include `undefined` in the domain of index signature values, and comments ([this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-286592106) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-286859503)) from the TS team lead about why they don't think it's a great idea (it would be worked around so often that it wouldn't actually provide safety in practice)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read most of the comments and I sitll think that the default type should include `undefined`. Main reason is that you might forget to add `undefined` yourself. Additionally you don't want to have `| undefined` in `forEach` or `entries` because in that case you know that it is not undefined. Most people in the github issue seem to agree with me. It's sad that the TS team does not want to change this as it is the reason for many runtime errors and the type is just wrong. I started using TypeScript to get type safety

Comment: @Nicholas Tower: That is only a partial solution because that would also mean that my code is allowed to assign `undefined` to a key when I really only want numbers to be assigned. Compare the definition of Maps in TS. That's the behavior that should also be the case for plain objects. I think many runtime errors can be avoided by having `undefined` in the type of an index operation. But sadly the TS team does not want to change that...

Comment: The difference between the implementation I (and apparently others) want and the suggested approach is that the type would be `number | undefined` when using `Object.values`, `.map()`, `.filter()`, etc., which is annoying. TypeScript should support correctly typing the result of a dynamic lookup as possibly undefined without allowing adding `undefined` to the object or incorrectly typing the items in the methods mentioned above as `number | undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Your `MyType` defines an index accessor that allows any number to be used as an accessor on an object:

```
type MyType = {
  [x: number] : number
}
```

This means that, as far as type safety, any number can be used to access the object using the index accessor, similar to an array.

Your object only defines a single property - but the type checker (compilation time) is not looking at your object, which is created a runtime. All the type checker knows about is `MyType`, and any number is a valid value to use to index any object whose type is or extends `MyType`.

You have to remember that your object, at runtime, is still just a regular old JavaScript object, and nothing about TypeScript applies once the code is compiled and running.

If you're looking to define a type with a set number of properties, then you should construct your type with a set number of properties instead of using an index accessor:

```
interface MyType {
  0: number
}

const o: MyType = { 0: 1 } // valid
const o2: MyType = { 1: 1 } // type checking error
o[0] // valid
o[1] // type checking error
```

Comment: Hard-Coding all possible keys is often not possible, for example when they are determined by user input. The TS compiler now assumes that all possible numbers are defined keys when using the `[key: number] : T` definition. But in reality that can't be true because there is an infinite number of possible keys. A common error is to access an invalid key from an object and that is currently not detected by the compiler. So I think this leads to many bugs that could be easily avoided. The Map type in TS does it correctly, only plain objects do it wrong

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you expect TypeScript to be able to do about data whose structure is defined at runtime. Even the `Map` object returns `undefined` when you call `.get()` with a key that doesn't exist - it is not an error.

Comment: Exactly! That is what I expect. The return type must include `undefined` (as `Map.get` does), but an index access on a plain object with props of type `[key: string] : SomeType` does not have `undefined` included in the type which leads to many errors. The type is just `SomeType`, but should be `SomeType | undefined` because not all keys exist.

Comment: Oh! You might be able to configure that. Try setting `"strict": true` in your `tsconfig.json` and go from there. For reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html -- particularly `strictNullChecks`

Comment: With that on, you should have to explicitly check for null / undefined when accessing a map or hash object

Comment: Even with the `strictNullChecks` option and `strict` set to `true` the type of an index access to an object is wrong. It does not include `undefined`. The TS team is aware of that, but they refuse to fix it for some non-convincing reasons: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778

Comment: In my opinion TS fails to fulfill its promise here: To avoid mistakes at runtime. If you read the thread that I posted, you'll see that I am not the only one who would like a change